# QueryInterceptor not firing

Tags: wcf, rest, odata

I created a QueryInterceptor on a dataservice in WCF (within SharePoint).

The "InitializeService" method is called and I'm able to debug that one,
but my QueryInterceptors don't get fired.

```
[QueryInterceptor("Requests")]
    public Expression<Func<Request, bool>> FilterRequests()
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        if (SPContext.Current == null) throw new DataServiceException(401, "Permission Denied");
        var spUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
        var spLoginName = spUser.LoginName;
        var spGroups = spUser.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().Select(x => x.Name);
        if (spGroups.Any(x => x == _HRApproversGroupName))
            return (u) => true;
        throw new DataServiceException(401, "Permission Denied");
    }

public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Users", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }
```

Anyone who knows what I'm doing wrong or haven't done yet?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I referenced to the wrong QueryInterceptor (I referenced to another assembly, but with same namespaces)